# Fix overlapping MouseListeners in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouselistener

I am running into an issue where it seems that the `MouseListener`s are overlapping each other.

In my application's GUI class, I added @camickr 's `ComponentResizer` class and registered my `JFrame`. When there are no subcomponents, or else, when I don't add other `MouseListener`s to the subcomponents, it works fine. But when I do so, the subcomponent seems to have the listener priority, and I am not able to resize the north border.

I tried the `addAWTEventListener()` method, like the following:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(event -> {
            if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
                MouseEvent e = (MouseEvent) event;
                if (e.getSource() == MainGUI.getMainFrame()) {
                    switch (e.getID()) {
                        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED -> mouseClicked(e);
                        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED -> mousePressed(e);
                        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED -> mouseReleased(e);
                        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED -> mouseEntered(e);
                        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED -> mouseExited(e);
                        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED -> mouseDragged(e);
                        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED -> mouseMoved(e);
                        default -> {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK);
```

But the results were very weird, with all the components in the frame being resizeable at the same time.

Here's an SSCCE of the problem:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MainGUI {

    private static JFrame mainFrame;
    private static JPanel contentPane;
    private static JPanel titleBar;

    private static ComponentResizer resizer = new ComponentResizer();

    public static void init() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame();
        contentPane = new JPanel();

        titleBar = new JPanel();
        titleBar.add(new JLabel("This is a title"));
        titleBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));

        // Problematic part. The resizer works correctly without it.
        titleBar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("You clicked me!");
            }
        });

        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.add(titleBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        mainFrame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        mainFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        mainFrame.setUndecorated(true);

        resizer.registerComponent(mainFrame);
    }

    public static void display() {
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setEnabled(true);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.requestFocus();
    }

    public static JFrame getMainFrame() {
        return mainFrame;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException |
                    IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            MainGUI.init();
            MainGUI.display();
        });
    }
}
```

And here's `ComponentResizer` class:

http://www.camick.com/java/source/ComponentResizer.java

So the question is, *is there a way to keep the `JFrame`'s listeners "on top" of the subcomponents listeners?*

Comment: Nice SSCCE example however I have a few comments for the future: 1) Use a single source file. The main() method can easily be added to your test class as I have done for you. Makes it easier for people to copy/paste/compile/test. 2) Don't use 3rd party classes. Most people won't download the class. You need to concentrate on the problem not your application. Your question is about using multiple MouseLIsteners. You don't need the ComponentResizer to demonstrate this. Just add another MouseListener to the frame with a mouseClicked event to demonstrate which listener has priority.

Comment: To add to the good advice you got:  try to avoid static fields, even more so when it comes to Components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way to keep the JFrame's listeners "on top" of the subcomponents listeners?

Not that I know of. Only a single component can receive the MouseEvent.

Swing will search the components from the bottom (of the parent / child component chain) to the top to find a component with a MouseListener and pass the event to that component. So the first component found with a listener will receive the event.

One solution is to provide a "wrapper" panel for your title bar with a `Border`.

For example:

```
    //  Create wrapper panel with a border

    JPanel wrapper = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    wrapper.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5) );
    wrapper.add(titleBar);

    contentPane.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   //contentPane.add(titleBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Now your title bar will NOT extend to the edges of the frame so the MouseEvent will be passed to the frame when the mouse is within 5 pixels of the edge.

You can also remove the Border from the title bar and use a `CompoundBorder` on the wrapper panel if you want the `LineBorder` to fully extend to the edge of the frame.

Note you will likely be adding components to the CENTER of the BorderLayout as well. If any of these components have a MouseListener you will have the same problem. Depending on your requirments you might want to consider adding the EmptyBorder to the content pane of the frame. This way you effectively add a Border to the entire frame.